# How can we reset Persistent Parameters to the default?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

In parameterized jobs using the Persistent Parameter Plugin,
does anybody have any ideas how we can reset these to the default values?

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Persistent+Parameter+Plugin